# Access GitHub API from Nifi

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, github-api

I'm trying to access info within GitHub's API from a NiFi Process. Essentially, I'm using GenerateFlowFile to set the target URL and the Authorization header for the token. I then pass it to the InvokeHTTP and every time it gets a 401 error saying it needs to be authenticated, despite providing my personal token (the one I use when programming locally and with Terminal). Any tips on how I can get this working? I can provide more detail if needed

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show terminal command line that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which endpoint you're trying to access in the GitHub API, but it appears you are using an endpoint from GitHub Enterprise 2.22 from the error message.

The docs for [authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#authentication) show you should prefix the token with `token` i.e:

```
Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN
```

In your specific case, this means you should set the `Authorization` header to `token ${github_token}`.

Comment: i am indeed using Enterprise, just wanted to err on the side of caution and blank out the identifying URL. In any case, this solution worked, thank you! I knew I included that token keyword in other scripts, but being new to Nifi I forgot it's necessity